# How to correctly serialize class derived from collection using DataContracts

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

In C# and .NET 4.5 I'm in the process of implementing XML generation/parsing by means of DataContract serialization which appears extremely effective.
I have, however, run into a number of problems in a couple of situations I hope somebody can help me with.

The relevant classes are the following 5 (plus a number of embedded objects):

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class ItemList<T> : List<T>, IList
  {
  .....
  }

[DataContract]
public class CashFlowList : ItemList<CashFlow>
  {
  .....
  }

[DataContract]
public class CashFlow : ItemList<CashFlowPayment>  
  {
  .....
  }

[DataContract]
public class CashFlowPayment : ListItem, IDataImportExport
  {
  .....
  }

[DataContract]
public abstract class ListItem : System.IComparable, IList
  {
  .....
  }
```

When using the DataContractSerializer (on the CashFlowList type), the resulting XML looks like this:

```
<CashFlowList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FinancialData">
  <_items>
    <CashFlow>
      <_items>
        <CashFlowPayment>
          <ID>-1</ID>
          <ProbDist xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProbabilityDistributions" i:nil="true" />
          <UseProbabilityDistribution>true</UseProbabilityDistribution>
          <ValidFrom>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
          <ValidThrough>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</ValidThrough>
          <Amount>4500</Amount>
          <Ccy i:nil="true" />
          <Date>2012-02-03T00:00:00</Date>
          <DaysFromStartDate>-1</DaysFromStartDate>
        </CashFlowPayment>
        <CashFlowPayment>
          <ID>-1</ID>
          <ProbDist xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProbabilityDistributions" i:nil="true" />
          <UseProbabilityDistribution>true</UseProbabilityDistribution>
          <ValidFrom>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
          <ValidThrough>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</ValidThrough>
          <Amount>-30000</Amount>
          <Ccy i:nil="true" />
          <Date>2013-04-10T00:00:00+02:00</Date>
          <DaysFromStartDate>465</DaysFromStartDate>
          <DaysUntilEndDate>-1</DaysUntilEndDate>
          <IsPerpetual>false</IsPerpetual>
          <PaymentType>Unknown</PaymentType>
          <Schedule xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Schedules" i:nil="true" />
        </CashFlowPayment>
        <CashFlowPayment i:nil="true" />
        <CashFlowPayment i:nil="true" />
      </_items>
      <_size>2</_size>
      <_version>3</_version>
      <ID>-1</ID>
      <Name></Name>
      <ProbDist xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProbabilityDistributions" i:nil="true" />
      <UseProbability>false</UseProbability>
      <ValidFrom>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
      <ValidThrough>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</ValidThrough>
      <BaseCCY></BaseCCY>

 ..............................

       <StartDate>2012-05-09T00:00:00</StartDate>
      <SumOfNegativePayments>-30000</SumOfNegativePayments>
      <SumOfPositivePayments>4500</SumOfPositivePayments>
      <ValueDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ValueDate>
      <XMLCashFlowElementName i:nil="true" />
      <XMLPaymentElementName i:nil="true" />
      <XMLPaymentsElementName i:nil="true" />
    </CashFlow>
    <CashFlow i:nil="true" />
    <CashFlow i:nil="true" />
    <CashFlow i:nil="true" />
  </_items>
  <_size>1</_size>
  <_version>1</_version>
  <ID>-1</ID>
  <Name></Name>
  <ProbDist xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProbabilityDistributions" i:nil="true" />
  <UseProbability>false</UseProbability>
  <ValidFrom>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
  <ValidThrough>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</ValidThrough>
</CashFlowList>
```

The generated XML is correct - but has a number of quirks: first of all the <_items> elements which I guess are required for the serializer to manage the output.
 Secondly, you will notice that each collection - within the <_items> elements always has a minimum of 4 child elements - for example, adding another CashFlow to the 
 outer  will result in only 2  elements - why, and is there a way of getting around that  ?

Replacing one or more [DataContract] attributes with [CollectionDataContract] - regardless of what properties are set within the attributes - will produce 
 grammatically correct XML output as expected, but now - for each class having the [CollectionDataContract] attribute - only the collection *items* are output - and not the regular 
 properties within the class. I.e. an example would be:

```
<CashFlowList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FinancialData">
  <CashFlow>
    <CashFlowPayment>
    ....
    </CashFlowPayment>      
  </CashFlow>    
</CashFlowList>
```

In the example above the following elements (in the outer CashFlowList object) have been ignored:

```
  <ID>-1</ID>
  <Name></Name>
  <ProbDist xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProbabilityDistributions" i:nil="true" />
  <UseProbability>false</UseProbability>
  <ValidFrom>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
  <ValidThrough>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</ValidThrough>
```

So my question is whether this is by design and is unavoidable - i.e. can you output a class derived from a collection and include additional properties in the output
when using the [CollectionDataContract] attribute ?

Interestingly, if [CollectionDataContract] attributes are used, you can generate/retrieve the corresponding XSD using the XsdDataContractExporter class without
problems (except that the XML is incomplete due to the missing properties). When using [DataContract] attributes, however, the XSD cannot be generated (fails in
the CanExport method), but the XML is correct and complete, but not particularly legible.

I would therefore really appreciate any insights and/or thoughts on this.

Best regards and thanks,

Michael

Comment: Have you tried XmlSerializer or LinqToXml?

Comment: @I4V:I considered XMLSerializer but this will give problems in that non-public setters are not supported which is not an option. LinqToXML can surely be used, but DataContractSerialization appears to fit the bill perfectly, except for the quirks.